# How to create comment, like, tag, report, and so on for a post model in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I created a model which name is Post and placed in this path : **MyProject/Postapp/models** look like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="posts",  
on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    message = models.TextField()
    message_html = models.TextField(editable=False)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name="posts",null=True, 
blank=True,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
         return self.message

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.message_html = misaka.html(self.message)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse(
            "posts:single",
            kwargs={
                "username": self.user.username,
                "pk": self.pk
            }
        )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-created_at"]
        unique_together = ["user", "message"]
```

So in the following, I want to add a comment, ... to each Post which created by Users. Should I start a new app (Commentapp, ...) or create models in the current path and add some fields in the Post model?

Comment: I would add a new model, `Comment`, to the same file where you defined your Post model. Or you can just say that a comment is just another `Post`. In that case your could add a this line `comment = models.ForeignKey(Post,...)` to your Post model.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18270898/django-best-practice-for-splitting-up-project-into-apps You'll get an idea _when_ to split code into apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is the same as for any "module" in any language (at least in any language that has some concept of modularity): you want strong cohesion (features of a module should be closely related) and low coupling (your module should have as few dependencies as possible, and you specially don't want cyclic dependencies).

In your case, `Comments` are obviously closely related to `Posts` so it makes perfect sense to keep them together (strong cohesion), while splitting them into different aps would actually add dependencies (and possibly cyclic ones) so it would increase coupling.

NB: unless you want a generic `comments` app that can work with any other model of course (in which case [one already exists](https://github.com/django/django-contrib-comments)), but from experience I would not get into this kind of premature generalization - most often than not you end up not using your "generic" model with anything else so all it buys you is only extra complexity (and quite some of it) for no real benefit. The mere point that the existing `contrib.comments` app was finally removed from the django trunk is a good enough sign that this was not a good candidate for a generic reusable app (as far as I'm concerned I used it once on a project, then dumped it and reimplement my own model which worked the way I needed with much less code and much better performances).